# Telethon: how to save groups/entities?

Tags: python, telethon

I would like to know how to save entities in telethon.

Currently, everytime I run my script, I have to run a query as such:

`testing_group = await client.get_entity('https://t.me/joinchat/****')`

Is there a way to save entities into my local file system such that I can retrieve them later? I tried using pickle, but even though I can dump and load entities, when I eventually do try to send a message to that entity, I get an error:

`Make sure to pass the right types, for instance making sure that the request is designed for channels or otherwise look for a different one more suited (caused by ForwardMessagesRequest)`

So it seems like pickle has modified the entity somehow.

I've read the [Session Docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/sessions.html), but don't understand if it's intention is for me to save groups/entities. A minimal working example would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get solution ?